# Decode a file encoded using base64 in Mac

Tags: java, macos, unix, decode, encode

I have a file that is base 64 encoded in a mac book -

```
base64 cwallet.sso > cwallet.base64.sso
```

How can decode this file using Java?

I tried using the code below , however the generated file is almost twice the size of original "cwallet.sso" file. When I code using `base64 -D cwallet.base64.sso > cwallet.original.sso` , I get the file that is of same size as that of cwallet.sso.

**Java Code**

```
File file = new File("<path>/cwallet_newfile.sso");
        String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("<path>/cwallet_base64.sso"), "UTF-8");
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(contents.trim());
        String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
        FileUtils.write(file,decodedString,"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't convert a (potentially) binary file to a UTF-8 `String`; instead write the `byte[]` with [`FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(File, byte[])`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile(java.io.File,%20byte[])) like

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(contents.trim());
// String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
// FileUtils.write(file,decodedString,"UTF-8");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, decodedBytes);
```